# Python high speed memcpy

Tags: python, c, memory-management, ctypes, high-speed-computing

I'm trying to do a high speed memcpy in Python. I use the ctypes library which allows me to interact with C programms.

I follow this steps:

1. I get the memory address
2. I get the length of the data
3. I use the ctypes' functions memmove or string_at

The results are correct but I need higher speed. Is there any faster way to do this without using C?

Thank you.

Comment: Show teh codez please

Comment: It seems doubtful that you can do this faster than `ctypes` can by any significant margin, if at all. Why do you need to copy memory so fast - [what problem are you actually trying to solve](http://xyproblem.info/) by doing this?

Comment: I found one solution in this post, in the answer of Hannah Zhang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808997/how-to-read-from-pointer-address-in-Python

Comment: If your problem is solved by an answer to another question, there is no need to post another answer linking to it; that answer exists and can be found by anyone searching for it. It also means your question is a duplicate.

Comment: It isn't the same question but the solution which was given in that case is good for this, so my question is not duplicated. ( Who reads both will know ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution in this post:

[How to read from pointer address in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808997/how-to-read-from-pointer-address-in-python)

In the answer of Hannah Zhang.