# Python ctypes: c_char_p not returning the correct value

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm new to Ctypes and trying to make a wrapper to use some dll functions but i'm facing a problem
first here is the code

C function structure

```
long func(char *pID);
```

Python code

```
lib = WinDLL("some.dll")
lib.func.restype = c_long
lib.func.argtypes = [c_char_p]
ID = c_char()
lib.func(byref(ID))
print(ID)
```

this outputs 8 which is correct but only the first character
the problem is I need the complete output not just the first char. I replaced it with c_char_p it give this c_char_p(925904440) which is a pointer but when I print its value (ID.value) it print an empty string   while c_char was giving the correct value why ?
also tried create_string_buffer(10) but gives an error
expected LP_c_char_p instance instead of pointer to c_char_Array_10

Notice : I'm writing a J2534 wrapper since all the libraries that I had found have some kind of error tried python libs and C# libs
if you know or have a working J2534 library then send me its link

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first character"? Is `func` supposed to fill a buffer with a C-style string?

Comment: yes it should return a string the expected output should be 8.07.696 but c_char returns only 8 which means it is correct but c_char_p return empty string

Comment: In that case I'd assume that `func` expects `pID` to be a pointer to a large enough buffer (however large that is - has to be documented somewhere) - in which case you need to first allocate that in your Python code and then construct a `c_char_p` referencing that buffer (which you can then pass into the function as parameter)

Comment: Note that if the function fills a UTF-16 LE buffer, ASCII characters will be followed by a null byte, and then the string will seem to be "one character long".

Answer (score 0):

You could use create_string_buffer. Documentation says:

> ctypes.create_string_buffer(init_or_size, size=None)
>
> This function creates a mutable character buffer. The returned object is a ctypes array of c_char.
>
> init_or_size must be an integer which specifies the size of the array, or a bytes object which will be used to initialize the array items.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer

An example could look like this:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("some.dll")
lib.func.restype = c_long
lib.func.argtype = c_char_p

buf = create_string_buffer(9)
lib.func(buf)
print(buf.value.decode("utf-8"))
```

A simple test function on the C-side could look like this:

```
#include <string.h>

static const char some_data[] = "8.07.696";

long func(char *p) {
    strcpy(p, some_data);
    return 1L;
}
```

This prints the expected result to the debug console:

```
8.07.696
```

Comment: For those of you wanted to avoid creating a string buffer and moving data into it, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48808997/. Though to decode it into a string you would need to make a Python list which is even less efficient so the move is fine.