# How to print c_void_p in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 'C' library returning c_void_p and c_ulong values. How to print the actual data in python?

When I print the c_void_p it prints an integer value 4899550 and c_ulong prints 32.

I am not asking to print the values, it is the actual data I need. How can we retrieve string data from those two ctypes?

Comment: Have you tried ``print``? What problem did you encounter when trying to display the data? Can you please [edit] your question to include a minimal example that we can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the way to print the actual data.
Say I got these values from the external C library, c_void_p ("buffer" value as integer)
and c_ulong ("bufferLength" as integer)

`import ctypes`

## Get the n characters from the memory.

`rawData = (ctypes.c_char*bufferLength.value).from_address(buffer.value)`

## Decode the raw data ascii and ignore any errors

`print(rawData.decode(encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')`

Thanks to this post:
[How to read from pointer address in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808997/how-to-read-from-pointer-address-in-python)