# Python mmap.read() with no pointer advancing

Tags: python, mmap

Is it possible to perform a mmap.read() (or equivalent) in Python without advancing the pointer?

I need to read the same address in a volatile memory over and over, and to optimise performance I don't want to have to seek to the same address each time.

```
file   = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
memory = mmap.mmap(f, 0x50000000, mmap.MAP_SHARED)

for index in range(1000000):
    memory.seek(address)

    # Unpack the bytes little-endian (least significant byte in first byte address etc.)
    data = struct.unpack("<L", memory.read(4))[0]
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from pointer address in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808997/how-to-read-from-pointer-address-in-python)

Comment: Try `memory[address:address+size]` since you can index mmap like a `bytearray`.

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python - the common point is `ctypes` in them. And the `[]` suggestion sounds plausible too.

Comment: @YiFei data = memory[address:address + 3] nearly works. I want to read 4 bytes, but it does not work as expected. If one sets size to 4, I think 5 bytes will be read which is not the intention.

Comment: @YiFei Actuallydata = memory[address:address + 4] works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

```
file   = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
memory = mmap.mmap(f, 0x50000000, mmap.MAP_SHARED)

for index in range(1000000):
    # Unpack the bytes little-endian (least significant byte in first byte address etc.)
    data = struct.unpack("<L", memory[address:address + 4])[0]
```

Thanks to @YiFei for the pointer. It has improved the speed of my code by 25%.

Comment: Trivial optimization: `[data] = struct.unpack("<L", memory[address:address + 4])`; unpacking works ever-so-slightly faster than indexing [when you want a single value in a single element sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696) (and if you ever make a mistake and unpack multiple values without adjusting the code, you'll get an error for not unpacking enough, where `[0]` will silently discard the rest of them).

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger That optimisation yielded another 3% improvement. I don't support you know of the syntax exploiting your optimisation to return struct.unpack("<L", memory[address:address + 4])? If I don't have to declare data that would perhaps be another optimisation!